# Extract pdf attachment on AWS S3 using iText Java

Tags: java, itext

I am using below **iText Java** code to extract attachments from PDF file. that work fine on local system. It extract XML file from PDF and stores on strOutputPath. I want to perform this operation on AWS S3. PDF file will on S3 and attachment should be extracted on S3. How I can use absolute path of file on S3 in this case. I used **s3client.getUrl().toExternalForm();** but I get HTTP 403 error.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

public class app
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            final String strInputPath = args[0];
            final String strOutputPath = args[1];
            final PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(strInputPath);
            final PdfDictionary catalog = pdfReader.getCatalog();

            final PdfDictionary names = catalog.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
            final PdfDictionary embeddedFiles = names.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
            final PdfArray embeddedFilesArray = embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);

            for (int i = 0; i < embeddedFilesArray.size(); ++i) {
                final PdfDictionary FileSpec = embeddedFilesArray.getAsDict(i);
                if (FileSpec != null) {
                    String strFileName = FileSpec.getAsString(PdfName.F).toString();
                    System.out.println(strFileName);
                    if (strFileName.endsWith(".xml")) {
                        strFileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".xml";
                        extractFiles(pdfReader, FileSpec, String.valueOf(strOutputPath) + strFileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void extractFiles(final PdfReader pdfReader, final PdfDictionary filespec, final String strFileName) {
        final PdfDictionary refs = filespec.getAsDict(PdfName.EF);
        PRStream prStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        final Set<PdfName> keys = (Set<PdfName>)refs.getKeys();
        try {
            for (final PdfName key : keys) {
                prStream = (PRStream)PdfReader.getPdfObject((PdfObject)refs.getAsIndirectObject(key));
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(strFileName));
                outputStream.write(PdfReader.getStreamBytes(prStream));
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload to s3 in a basic example use case using java?

Comment: Have you considered using `byte[]` for the data in-between? Download the PDF from S3 into a `byte[]` and create a `PdfReader` from that `byte[]`. The use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as target in `extractFiles` and thereafter retrieve the `byte[]` from that stream and upload that `byte[]` to S3. That should allow you to use standard S3 example code for the S3 communication and standard iText code, too..

Comment: @epoch Yes I can upload

Comment: @what is the difference between that upload and this one, can you see where im going ;-)

Comment: @epoch for that they have putObject. here I have to pass absolute path of files on s3 to iText pdf extract functionality. and I don't understand how I can give this path

Comment: the putObjectRequest has a `withInputStream` method, instead of using the absolute path you could be using `req.withInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(getStreamBytes(...)))`

Comment: However, if you post the code your are actually using in a self contained example, it would help a lot, you have no S3 code or stacktraces in your question, which makes helping you quite difficult.

Comment: I am using s3client.getUrl("bucket", "key").toExternalForm();
and using this path in strInputPath  and strOutputPath

Comment: @mkl I am not regular java user. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is write a Java client that works on the files on your S3 bucket and performs following steps:

- Downloads the required file from S3.
- Extracts the attachment from the file.
- Uploads the resultant files back to S3.

Sample code the perform above mentioned steps is as follows :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Set;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

public class S3PDFAttachmentExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // download file from S3
    AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
    S3Object object = amazonS3Client.getObject("<yours3location>", "fileKey");

    // write the file content to a local file.
    S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("tempOutputFile.pdf");
    writeToFile(objectContent, out);

    // Extract attachment from the downloaded file.
    extractAttachment("tempOutputFile.pdf", "tempAttachement.xml");

    //upload the attachment
    uploadFile("<s3bucket.fully.qualified.name>", "tempAttachement.xml", "attachementNameOnS3.xml");

    }

    private static void writeToFile(InputStream input, FileOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    // Read the text input stream one line at a time and display each line.
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input);) {
        byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
        while (in.read(chunk) > 0) {
        out.write(chunk);
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
    }

    public static void extractAttachment(final String strInputPath, final String strOutputPath) {
    try {
        final PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(strInputPath);
        final PdfDictionary catalog = pdfReader.getCatalog();
        final PdfDictionary names = catalog.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
        final PdfDictionary embeddedFiles = names.getAsDict(PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
        final PdfArray embeddedFilesArray = embeddedFiles.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
        for (int i = 0; i < embeddedFilesArray.size(); ++i) {
        final PdfDictionary FileSpec = embeddedFilesArray.getAsDict(i);
        if (FileSpec != null) {
            String strFileName = FileSpec.getAsString(PdfName.F).toString();
            System.out.println(strFileName);
            if (strFileName.endsWith(".xml")) {
            strFileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".xml";
            extractFiles(pdfReader, FileSpec, String.valueOf(strOutputPath) + strFileName);
            }
        }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private static void extractFiles(final PdfReader pdfReader, final PdfDictionary filespec, final String strFileName) {
    final PdfDictionary refs = filespec.getAsDict(PdfName.EF);
    PRStream prStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    final Set<PdfName> keys = (Set<PdfName>) refs.getKeys();
    try {
        for (final PdfName key : keys) {
        prStream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject((PdfObject) refs.getAsIndirectObject(key));
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(strFileName));
        outputStream.write(PdfReader.getStreamBytes(prStream));
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
        } catch (IOException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        if (outputStream != null) {
        outputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private static void uploadFile(String bucketFullPath, String fileLocation, String fileName) throws IOException {
    AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
    InputStream bis = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setContentType("application/xml");
    amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketFullPath, fileName, bis, objectMetadata);
    }
}
```

**Please note** that a better way to do this type of thing is to write a [AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) in Java using the above code. Since AWS Lambada can be easily configured to process events from S3 Storage, your code will automatically get invoked when a file is written or modified in S3 bucket. For further details you can check the [AWS Lambda Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

**Edit**:
Another alternative is - If you are running the Java code on AWS EC2, then there is a way to [mount a S3 bucket as a file System](https://cloudkul.com/blog/mounting-s3-bucket-linux-ec2-instance/). This will allow you access files as if these files are stored locally, And your original code will work. But this approach will work only on AWS EC2 environment.

Comment: I want a way to do it on S3. I am already doing this way.  I want to avoid this download / upload.

Comment: Yes but you cannot run Java code on S3, you will need Java runtime to execute java code, it cannot be done directly on S3.

Comment: An alternate way that's coming to my mind is - If you are running the Java code on AWS EC2, then there is a way to mount a S3 bucket as a file System. This will allow you access files as if these files are stored locally, And your original code will work.
But this approach work only on AWS EC2 environment.

Comment: I will check that . Still I don't understand why I can not use file from S3 as input here. java code executes on server not on S3. just input and output path are of S3